# RxSwift keep state of string without a Subject or a Variable

Tags: swift, mvvm, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I want to convert a ViewModel that I already have to be full Rx.
The application evaluates arithmetic expressions.

The ViewModel has two strings, one with 'logical' symbols, that will be send to the expression evaluator to get a result, and a 'presentation' string with other symbols that will be showed in the UI.

The ViewController calls a VM function, 'keyPressed(keyID: Int)' that will be used to modify both the 'logical' string, and the 'presentation' string, the 'keyPressed' uses the right symbol for the right string and modify it by appending the new symbol.

How can I convert the VM to be reactive without having any state (any string) or at least not having the presentation string?

Comment: Could you provide some code of what you already have? Because otherwise the answer would be something generic like this: "Observe the keyID via some observable and update the presentation whenever it changes" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not want to keep state I´m assuming you´d like to transform your logical symbol string into a stream which will then be mapped or observed by the expression evaluation code. In this case, you can have `keyPressed(keyID: Int)` push values to a PublishSubject and then create the logical expression stream by applying the `scan` operator to the `subject.asObservable`.

Here is a post that may help:
http://rx-marin.com/post/rxswift-state-with-scan/

Answer (score 0):

```
//in viewModel
let logical = Variable<String>("")
let presentation = Variable<String>("")

func keyPressed(keyID: Int) {

    //do
    logical.value = "what?"
    presentation.value = "what?"
}

//in controller
func youWantToDo() {

    logical.asObservable().subscribe(onNext: <#T##((String) -> Void)?##((String) -> Void)?##(String) -> Void#>, onError: <#T##((Error) -> Void)?##((Error) -> Void)?##(Error) -> Void#>, onCompleted: <#T##(() -> Void)?##(() -> Void)?##() -> Void#>, onDisposed: <#T##(() -> Void)?##(() -> Void)?##() -> Void#>)

    presentation.asObservable().bind(to: <#T##ObserverType#>)
}
```